# Adding createdAt and updatedAt in pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to add auto generated field `created_at` and `updated_at` in mongodb in python using `pymongo`.

This functionality is provided in Javascript when creating mongo schema using

```
var yourSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'} });
```

How exactly can this be done in pymongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `mongoose` feature, not to be confused with javascript or MongoDB.
`pymongo` does not offer such capabilities.

You will just have to manually specify them in your operations, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

db.collection.updateOne({
   "key": 5
},
{
  "$set": { "updated_at": datetime.now() },
  "$setOnInsert": { "created_at": datetime.now() }
}, upsert=True)
```